# error al tratar de abrir una aplicación hecha en VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2010

tengo este error al tratar de abrir una aplicacion hecha en vs 2012
alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo
muchas gracias

Firma con problemas:

```
Nombre del evento de problema:  CLR20r3

  Firma del problema 01:    gebot.exe

  Firma del problema 02:    1.0.0.0

  Firma del problema 03:    58cafcb0

  Firma del problema 04:    SharpDX

  Firma del problema 05:    2.4.2.0

  Firma del problema 06:    50d47ba9

  Firma del problema 07:    920

  Firma del problema 08:    14

  Firma del problema 09:    SharpDX.SharpDXException

  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.11

  Id. de configuración regional:    1040

  Información adicional 1:  0a9e

  Información adicional 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

  Información adicional 3:  0a9e

  Información adicional 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Lea nuestra declaración de privacidad en línea:

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0c0a
```

Si la declaración de privacidad en línea no está disponible, lea la declaración de privacidad sin conexión:

```
  C:\Windows\system32\es-ES\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese error puede variar entre un dll que hayas olvidado incluir en el instalador o selecionado un paquete de idiomas y la computadora que va usar el programa no tenga el mismo lenguaje o configuración regional.

Yo tuve el mismo problema, y como yo muchos no encontraron la solución debido a que windows no detalla el error apropiadamente. La solución ideal sería crear un formulario en blanco y agregar un botón que llame al programa principal o tu otro formulario inicial, y con un try tratar de devolver el error que genera al momento de corre el programa en la máquina cliente. En mi caso era un función que en el visual no tiraba error, pero ya una vez instalada no podía hacer referencia a algunos formularios, lo único que hice fue comentar esa función y el programa comenzó a funcionar adecuadamente.